# Fresh CoreOS install hangs during boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, boot-loader, coreos

I decided to replace windows 7 with CoreOS on my computer for research and learning purposes. I was able to successfully install CoreOS version 766.4.0 from a USB drive but after restarting the computer to boot off the freshly installed OS. Every time I attempt to boot it hangs at the screen where it shows:

```
booting 'coreos default'  

_
```

There shouldn't be any problem with the ISO file itself because CoreOS properly boots when installed in VirtualBox I have on a separate laptop. 
Also the installation itself does not seem to be suspect because it successfully completes in both the virtualbox environment and on the physical hardware of my home computer. In both cases I used the the `sudo coreos-install -d /dev/sda` command to install it. I chose not to use the `-c` option and the `cloud-config` YAML file because i can just login normally.

One thing I noticed though is that when I installed it on the hardware it printed `*SYSLINUX* ... Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin` and when it was installed it on the VirtualBox machine it read `*ISOLINUX* ... Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin` which makes me suspect the problem may be a SYSLINUX incompatibility bug with the hardware because I installed CoreOS on a SATA3 60GB SSD and according to what I have read about CoreOS it is a fairly new distro and largely undocumented. I don't know enough about the linux kernel or boot process to test this hypothesis though.

This is my first question post so let me know if I left out something important or you need something clarified. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I should add that I used the program UNetbootin to create the LiveCD usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you installed.  The supported method is this:

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/installing-to-disk.html

Is that what you did?

CoreOS, for what it's worth, is not intended to be a laptop/desktop OS; it's specifically engineered toward cloud and containerized computing. Don't let that stop you, if you are having fun, but if you're looking for a desktop OS, then CoreOS does not purport to be that.

Comment: Yep. That is the guide I followed. I figured I could use a container to host a desktop os for the things I normally use the computer for.